# How to use RestSharp with async/await

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, restsharp

I'm struggling to find a modern example of some asynchronous C# code that uses RestSharp with `async` and `await`. I know there's [been a recent update by Haack](http://haacked.com/archive/2013/09/18/restsharp-104-2-0-released.aspx/) but I don't know how to use the new methods.

Also, how can I provide a cancellation token so that the operation can be canceled (say, if a person is sick of waiting and presses the Cancel button in the app's UI).

Answer (score 227, accepted):

Well, the update Haack is referring to has been made by me :) So let me show you how to use it, as it is actually very simple. Previously you had methods like `ExecuteAsyncGet` that would return a RestSharp custom type named `RestRequestAsyncHandle`. This type could not be awaited as `async/await` works on `Task` and `Task<T>` return types. My pull-request added overloads to the existing async methods that return `Task<T>` instances. These `Task<T>` overloads have an added "Task" string added to their names, for example the `Task<T>` overload for `ExecuteAsyncGet` is called `ExecuteGetTaskAsync<T>`. For each of the new `Task<T>` overloads there is one method that does not require a `CancellationToken` to be specified and there is one that does.

So now on to an actual example on how to use it, which will also show how to use a `CancellationToken`:

```
private static async void Main()
{
    var client = new RestClient();
    var request = new RestRequest("http://www.google.com");
    var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

    var restResponse = 
        await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token);

    // Will output the HTML contents of the requested page
    Console.WriteLine(restResponse.Content); 
}
```

This will use the `ExecuteTaskAsync` overload that returns a `Task<IRestResponse>` instance. As it returns a `Task`, you can use the `await` keyword on this method and get returned the `Task<T>`'s returned type (in this case `IRestResponse`).

You can find the code here: http://dotnetfiddle.net/tDtKbL

Comment: AH! I think I :heart: you!! (And very apt, considering it's Valentines day). This would be VERY nice to add to the RestSharp wiki. Ok, so .. any chance there's a PCL of this, also? Or am I pushing my luck?

Comment: I'm not sure if a PCL version of this would work, but I will look into it in the future. And I agree it would be nice to add to the wiki, don't know if I'm allowed to edit it (I'm not a regular maintainer of the library).

Comment: Maybe we can get @Haacked into the convo, maybe on Twitter?

Comment: +1. @ErikSchierboom: I have a lot of PCL async experience. You can ping me if you have any questions (or just post on SO).

Comment: @ErikSchierboom Do you know if there is a way to port it to Windows Phone 8? I cannot find the function ExecuteTaskAsync on Windows Phone.

Comment: @poiuytrez I think it could be ported as Windows Phone 8, but I'm not sure unfortunately.

Comment: I found the solution: http://danielgary.net/awaitable-restsharp-for-windows-phone/

Comment: How can I map to my custom IRestResponse implementation?

Comment: Because I last used Restsharp around the same time shoulder pads were en vogue, rotary phones were the norm and we all loved hitting up our fav BBS via our Robotics 14.4k modem. 

Green tick of answer-approval, I shall.

Comment: @jpgrassi It is quite some time, but I was now thinking about the same. It is possible to call it like: `await client.ExecuteTaskAsync<TModel>(request, cancellationTokenSource.Token)` where `TModel` is class to be mapped from response.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This technique makes RestSharp better that other API management tools.

Comment: Thanks! I was trying to figure out how get RestSharp to call asyncly in my async method. They don't make it super clear in their naming methods. ExecuteAsync doesnt act like you think it would.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, but i m not able to generate the output, so i tried the t.Wait(); then the output came for my console application. Is it correct?

Answer (score 3):

In my case, I had to call Task.Wait() for it to work properly. However, I used the version which does not take CancellationTokenSource as parameter.

```
private static async void Main()
{
    var client = new RestClient();
    var request = new RestRequest("http://www.google.com");
    Task<IRestResponse> t = client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request);
    t.Wait();
    var restResponse = await t;
    Console.WriteLine(restResponse.Content); // Will output the HTML contents of the requested page
}
```

Comment: By using `Wait` you're not leveraging async code, you're just running it synchronously.

Comment: In my case calling ExecuteTaskAsynk (with or without the cancellation token) does not return and make the IIS irresponsive. I had to use this HACK until I found the cause.

Comment: if you wait why dont you just use the sync version of the call... pointless

Comment: Aren't you freeing the Thread to be used elsewhere though? On a long-running operation on the other end that's beneficial, no?

Comment: yes, output came, whether the answer is valid, Am i achieving the Async operation.